# App Store Connect API: The relationship expects data as an array but an object was given

Tags: api, rest, app-store-connect

Trying to add builds to specific TestFlight beta groups using the App Store Connect API. This is the endpoint I am trying to access:

```
POST https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/builds/{id}/relationships/betaGroups
```

Docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/add_access_for_beta_groups_to_a_build

I am running into issues with the body of my request. My current structure is:

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "betaGroups",
        "id": "[group id]"
    }
}
```

And I am getting the error output.

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "id": "c7bc3b27-3ce5-49c9-8e1e-e3ff80bd2b15",
            "status": "409",
            "code": "ENTITY_ERROR.RELATIONSHIP.INVALID",
            "title": "The provided relationships data has an invalid value",
            "detail": "The relationship expects data as an array but an object was given.",
            "source": {
                "pointer": "/data"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I get from the message that something has to be an array, but I'm not sure what. I've tried reading the api documentation, but information seems sparse at best, so would appreciate any help you guys could give.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution to my own question!!

Using this link (https://medium.com/xcblog/wwdc18-a-basic-guide-to-app-store-connect-api-366208651ac6) I released the request body had to be:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "type": "betaGroups",
        "id": "[group id]"
    }]
}
```